# Play Local Video File

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, avplayer

I have followed a tutorial and trying to get a video to pop up when I press a button. The video pops up but the actual video does not start playing and I just get this screen....

[Blank Screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6zGv.png)

the code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var player:AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let videoString:String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "motorbikes", ofType: ".m4v")

        if let url = videoString {
            let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)

            self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: {

            self.playerController.player?.play()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have not set `player` of `playerController` ?

Comment: Where and how should i set it?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. i have managed to sort it out

the code missing was...

self.playerController,player = self.player

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgot to set playercontroller's player instance as [phuc-nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3557350/phuc-nguyen) said

or else you can make use of ***AVPlayerLayer*** to play the video without using ***AVPlayerViewController***

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "path/myvideo.mp4")!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

Using ***AVPlayerLayer*** you can customize the player like adding your own controls or views and it won't be a full screen view usually though.

But if you are not looking for any customization its good to stick with **AVPlayerViewController** it has all the controls baked in

Depends on your requirement